# Get collections in subcollections and subcollections

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem with the firestore. The problem is that I have such a database. And I'd like to download all the stuff in the hives collection. The problem is that there are different collections for each of the apiaries. I have, for example: 3 documents in apiaries and for each apiaries and in each document I have, for example: 5 hives. And I would like all the details from all the hives.

```
users:
  {uid}:
    apiaries:
      {uid}:
        hives:
          {uid}
    notes:
      {uid}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get all of the documents in all of the subcollections named "hives", no matter where they are nested, then you will want to use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

```
firebase.firestore().collectionGroup("hives").get()
```

Comment: I wanted to add a comment, but something the code format breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this. Is this fairly correct? Do I have to change anything in the database?

```
async getHives() {
      await fb.usersCollection
        .doc(fb.auth.currentUser.uid)
        .collectionGroup('hives')
        .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
          let hivesArray = [];

          snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            let hive = doc.data();
            hive.id = doc.id;

            hivesArray.push(hive);
          });

          store.commit('setHives', hivesArray);
        });
    },
```